# Mongo db row by row operation and validation

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

We have a large mongodb collection. On that we need to perform periodic row by row operations. We use pymongo. We have the code that dynamically generates filter condition in mongodb format and that part of the code can not change.

The current code looks somthing like this

```
for row in cursor:
   do_row_by_row_op_if_filter_is_invalid(row)

cursor.rewind()

for row in cursor.find(filter_in_mongo_db_format):
   do_row_by_row_op_if_filter_is_valid(row)
```

This is not optimal at all. How can we do something like

```
for row in cursor:
   if not filter_is_valid(row, filter_in_mongo_db_format):
       do_row_by_row_op_if_filter_is_invalid(row)
   else:
       do_row_by_row_op_if_filter_is_valid(row)
```

Comment: so you want to use the filter_in_mongo_db_format for validating the row (already in cursor), and then decide which operation to perform, right? ..... if that is the case, one solution could be `for row in cusor: insert_this_row_into_temp_db and row=findOne(filter_in_mongo_db_format)` If you get back NULL, the row was invalid, else valid

Comment: Unless there is some data guarantee, first code and second are not identical in effect. Are first cursor's result and second cursor's result (in first code) disjoint? Or, maybe the `is_invalid` function does not alter the result of `filter`? (I'm just trying to understand the situation) Also, `cursor` has no `find` method, I assumed you meant `collection`.